# Makefile pattern rules with regex

Tags: regex, makefile

I need to convert a bunch of files with names like this:

`bar_S4_R1_001.fastq.gz`

`bar_S4_R2_001.fastq.gz`

Into files with names like this:

`bar_R1_001.fastq.gz`

`bar_R2_001.fastq.gz`

I would like to do it with a Makefile [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) ([docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html#Pattern-Match), [examples](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Examples.html))

I have a Makefile like this:

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash
files:
    touch foo_S13_R2_001.fastq.gz
    touch foo_S13_R1_001.fastq.gz
    touch bar_S4_R2_001.fastq.gz
    touch bar_S4_R1_001.fastq.gz
    touch baz_S9_R2_001.fastq.gz
    touch baz_S9_R1_001.fastq.gz

FILES:=$(shell find . -name "*.fastq.gz")
.PHONY: $(FILES)

demo: $(FILES)
$(FILES):
    @printf "source: $@ , target should be: " ; \
    echo "$@" | sed -e 's|\(_S[0-9]*\)\(_R[12]_001.fastq.gz\)$$|\2|'
```

example:

```
$ make files
touch foo_S13_R2_001.fastq.gz
touch foo_S13_R1_001.fastq.gz
touch bar_S4_R2_001.fastq.gz
touch bar_S4_R1_001.fastq.gz
touch baz_S9_R2_001.fastq.gz
touch baz_S9_R1_001.fastq.gz

$ make demo
source: bar_S4_R1_001.fastq.gz , target should be: bar_R1_001.fastq.gz
source: foo_S13_R2_001.fastq.gz , target should be: foo_R2_001.fastq.gz
source: bar_S4_R2_001.fastq.gz , target should be: bar_R2_001.fastq.gz
source: baz_S9_R2_001.fastq.gz , target should be: baz_R2_001.fastq.gz
source: baz_S9_R1_001.fastq.gz , target should be: baz_R1_001.fastq.gz
source: foo_S13_R1_001.fastq.gz , target should be: foo_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

Obviously, I have my "source" and "target" backwards in the 'demo' recipe here. How can I use a Makefile pattern rule for this instead to make the correct file?

Comment: It might be easier to use rename instead: `rename 's/S\d+_//' *.fastq.gz`

Comment: thanks but I have other reasons for using a Makefile as well, independent of the issue in this question

Answer (score 2):

Tricky but doable with GNU make thanks to the (in-)famous [`foreach-eval-call`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) combination and the [string substitution and analysis functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions):

```
SHELL         := /bin/bash
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
FILES         := foo_S13_R2_001.fastq.gz foo_S13_R1_001.fastq.gz bar_S4_R2_001.fastq.gz bar_S4_R1_001.fastq.gz baz_S9_R2_001.fastq.gz baz_S9_R1_001.fastq.gz
TARGETS       :=

.PHONY: all

# $(1): name of the source file in X_Y_Z_T.fastq.gz form
# tmp: X Y Z T.fastq.gz
# tmp1: X
# tmp2: Y
# tmp3: Z
# tmp4: T.fastq.gz
define MYRULE
tmp  := $$(subst _, ,$(1))
tmp1 := $$(word 1,$$(tmp))
tmp2 := $$(word 2,$$(tmp))
tmp3 := $$(word 3,$$(tmp))
tmp4 := $$(word 4,$$(tmp))

$$(tmp1)_$$(tmp3)_$$(tmp4): $(1)
    @printf 'source: %s, target should be: %s\n' "$$<" "$$@"

TARGETS += $$(tmp1)_$$(tmp3)_$$(tmp4)
endef
$(foreach f,$(FILES),$(eval $(call MYRULE,$(f))))

all: $(TARGETS)

$(FILES):
    @touch $@
```

Demo:

```
$ make
source: foo_S13_R2_001.fastq.gz, target should be: foo_R2_001.fastq.gz
source: foo_S13_R1_001.fastq.gz, target should be: foo_R1_001.fastq.gz
source: bar_S4_R2_001.fastq.gz, target should be: bar_R2_001.fastq.gz
source: bar_S4_R1_001.fastq.gz, target should be: bar_R1_001.fastq.gz
source: baz_S9_R2_001.fastq.gz, target should be: baz_R2_001.fastq.gz
source: baz_S9_R1_001.fastq.gz, target should be: baz_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

Note: the double `$$` in the `MYRULE` definition are essential, just  like the `:=` variable assignments (instead of the `=` recursive assignments).

Answer (score 1):

The first solution is vanilla make:

```
PAT_START := _S
PAT_MID := 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
PAT_END := 0_ 1_ 2_ 3_ 4_ 5_ 6_ 7_ 8_ 9_

SUBSTITUTE := _

PAT12 := $(foreach c,$(PAT_START),$(addprefix $(c),$(PAT_END)))
PAT123 := $(foreach c,$(foreach c,$(PAT_START),$(addprefix $(c),$(PAT_MID))),$(addprefix $(c),$(PAT_END)))

$(info $(PAT12))
$(info $(PAT123))

FILES := foo_S13_R2_001.fastq.gz foo_S13_R1_001.fastq.gz bar_S4_R2_001.fastq.gz bar_S4_R1_001.fastq.gz baz_S9_R2_001.fastq.gz baz_S9_R1_001.fastq.gz

NEW_FILES := $(strip $(foreach f,$(FILES),$(foreach p,$(PAT12) $(PAT123),$(if $(subst $(subst $(p),,$(f)),,$(f)),$(subst $(p),$(SUBSTITUTE),$(f))))))

$(info $(FILES))
$(info $(NEW_FILES))
```

The second is using [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt), a `GNUmake` library which is eases such tasks a great deal:

```
include gmtt-master/gmtt-master/gmtt.mk

NEW_FILES := $(foreach f,$(FILES),$(call implode,$(call pick,1 4 5 6 7,$(call glob-match,$(f),*_S*_R[0-9]_*))))

$(info $(FILES))
$(info $(NEW_FILES))
```

Note that the gmtt solution is using a *glob* not a RE.